# What are the markings found on a purple clay teapot?

Tags: translation, character-identification

I am trying to find information on this modern? Chinese purple clay tea pot.  Can anyone translate this for me?  Thank you
[image]

Comment: 東寶鍾製 It seems to be.

Comment: thank you.  google says that means Dōng bǎo zhōng zhì in pinyin.  After a lot of google searches I am wondering if it is just the  name of the person or company and can't really be translated into english.  I was trying to date the purple clay teapot, or find out more about when and where it was made.  Sure it is modern, but thought maybe mid century.  thank you so much for your help

Comment: In Simplified Chinese: 东宝钟制.

Comment: @BarbaraSwangerEndzel It may be 鍾東寶製, if read clockwise. I ve done some google searches too but there isn't much info. I guess the maker is infamous or unimportant.

Comment: @BarbaraSwangerEndzel, yes, this style of arranging characters in a block like this is very typical of East Asian Seals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_(East_Asia)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's 車寶鍾製. Accidentally found one item selling online with the same seal. https://tw.bid.yahoo.com/item/%E6%97%A9%E6%9C%9F%E8%80%81%E8%8C%B6%E5%A3%BA-%E8%BB%8A%E5%AF%B6%E9%8D%BE%E6%AC%BE-100433885065

車寶鍾 is the name of the person who made this.

Comment: Good find, but that isn't the same seal. The first character looks slightly different at the top, and the second character is 宝 in your picture rather than 寶 in the question. Still, it might be a different person named 車寶鍾.

Comment: I would probably believe that could be the same person having two different seals :)